# Setting up code coverage for Catch2 tests when building on CMake with Visual Studio toolchain: unknown option "-ftest-coverage"

Tags: c++, cmake, gcov

I am trying to generate gcov files from my catch2 tests, which are built using CMake, with the Visual Studio 2017 toolchain.

From everything that I have read, the first step for this is as follows:

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -O0 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-g -O0 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")

cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-ftest-coverage'
```

But it appears that the compiler doesn't recognize these arguments. Are there alternative flags I need to be using? Or is it just not possible?

If it's not possible to use gcov, is there a tool I can use which will generate compatible output files? I need to generate coverage files compatible with SonarQube.

Comment: _"...gcov is a code coverage tool for GCC..."_

Comment: Visual Studio ≠ GNU GCC